# Sequence in existing table

Tags: teradata

I have an existing table in teradata which is skewed due to multiple indexes.. can you please help me in creating sequence as Identity column so that I could add that sequence in the table and make an index to it.

Comment: Teradata is processing in parallel.  Due to this you can create an identity but it won't necessarily be sequential.  To change the distribution of the table to reduce the skew you need a different primary index.  In order to change the primary index you are going to need to actually create a new table.

Comment: If you need to create a sequential identifier try using row_number()

Comment: Adding a sequence will probably not improve performance. What's the current DDL, PK & FKs and skew?

Comment: Yeah... Row() number served the purpose... however PK was applied to name column and no fk ...

Comment: Row_number () will eliminate the skewness but will most likely force the joins to use non-PI access paths which will make join performance slower. PI selection is a critical element in overall system performance.